# Is it possible to cast View to ViewGroup?

Tags: android, recursion, android-viewgroup

```
  private void scaleAllViews(ViewGroup parentLayout) {

        int count = parentLayout.getChildCount();
        Log.d(TAG, "scaleAllViews: "+count);
        View v = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            try {
                v = parentLayout.getChildAt(i);

                if(((ViewGroup)v).getChildCount()>0){
                   scaleAllViews((ViewGroup)v);
                }else{
                    if (v != null) {
                        v.setScaleY(0.9f);
                    }
                }

            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

I created a recursive function to access child items of view group, but the  `parentLayout.getChildAt(i);`  returns a `View`, which contains children too, so I need to access that, but after casting I get the error `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if it is a `ViewGroup` before casting to `ViewGroup`.

```
if(v instanceof ViewGroup) {
    // now this is a safe cast
    ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) vg;
    // ... use this ViewGroup
} else {
    // It's some other type of View
}
```

Answer (score 2):

ViewGroup is a sub class of View. So if the object you have is an instance of ViewGroup, then yes you certainly can.

You should check if the view is an instanceof ViewGroup before you do your casting to ensure no exceptions are thrown.